# How to cache gravatar avatars?

Tags: php

How can I cache gravatar avatars for faster loading?

Currently I am just using a directly link:
`<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5( strtolower( trim( "privat@marktopper.dk" ) ) ) . '" alt="" class="comment-avatar"/>`

Comment: gravatars are publicly cached, so your code looks fine.

Comment: You're serving them up from `gravatar.com`, it's not your business to cache them, it's theirs. I'm sure gravatar is doing a very good job of this already.

Answer (score 3):

You could use curl on your server to get the gravatars and cache them yourself, but I'm certain that gravatar.com will also cache them, as may the client browser, so I think you will not gain much.

Comment: that would be nothing special with gravatar. However I could imagine if you get the gravatar CDN url / notation, you could gain a benefit.

Answer (score 2):

I have write down some functions that do caching of gravatar images locally see the example.

Please change this line `$gravatar_email = "default@email.com";` to your gravatar default email before testing.

This line also `$your_domain = "http://www.simplestudio.rs";` to your domain.

And this line `$local_file = "images/users/" . $email . "." . $type;`to your local path.

```
<?php

function img_type($get_img) {

    $type_img = explode("\n", $get_img);
    $type_img = $type_img[0];
    $type_img = strtolower($type_img);
    $type_img = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$type_img);

    $ftypes = array("png","jpg","jpeg","gif","bmp");

    $ftype = "";
    foreach($ftypes as $ft) {

        $locate_type = strpos($type_img, $ft);
        if($locate_type > -1) {

            $ftype = $ft;
            break;

        }

    }

    return $ftype;

}

function user_img($email, $size, $days_to_cache) {

    $email = strtolower(trim($email));

    $your_domain = "http://www.simplestudio.rs";
    $default_user_img = $your_domain . "/yard/gravatar/images/users/default_user.png";

    $gravatar_img = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5($email) . "?s=" . $size . "&d=" . $default_user_img;

    $now_day = date("Ymd");

    global $now_minus_one;
    $period_to_chk = " -" . $days_to_cache . " day";
    $now_minus_one = date('Ymd', strtotime($now_day . $period_to_chk));

    $get_img = file_get_contents($gravatar_img);

    $type = img_type($get_img);

    $local_file = "images/users/" . $email . "." . $type;

    if (file_exists($local_file)) {

        global $file_date;
        $file_date = date("Ymd", filemtime($local_file));

        if($now_minus_one >= $file_date) {

            $get_img = file_get_contents($gravatar_img);

            $open_file = fopen($local_file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            $data = $get_img;
            fwrite($open_file, $data);
            fclose($open_file);

            $user_img = $local_file;

        }
        else {

            $user_img = $local_file;

        }

    }
    else {

        $open_file = fopen($local_file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $data = $get_img;
        fwrite($open_file, $data);
        fclose($open_file);

        $user_img = $local_file;

    }

    return $user_img;

}

if(isset($_REQUEST['gravatar_email'])) {

    $gravatar_email = $_REQUEST['gravatar_email'];

}
else {

    $gravatar_email = "default@email.com";

}

$img = user_img($gravatar_email, "64", "1");

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="<?php print $img; ?>" alt="" class="comment-avatar"/>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here it is in action:**
http://simplestudio.rs/yard/gravatar/gravatar.php

- you can pass parameter for email in URL just add ?gravatar_email=some@mail.com

**This is where images are saved:**
http://simplestudio.rs/yard/gravatar/images/users/

So what is the logic?
You call function that gets gravatar via email address and it checks if that gravatar is already cached.
If it is not it just save file locally and return that path to you.
If it is already saved it checks if that file is older then 1 day (this is configurable in function parameters - 3rd parameter) and if it is older it updates gravatar if not it serve old local file.
Also when you call the function you can configure what size of gravatar do you need, for test I put 64px...
Also there is a fail over img defined variable `$default_user_img` and if user does not have gravatar then your local failover img will be default which is always good to have...

I think that if you cache images from gravatar in this way it will be faster when you look long term.
Anyway you will have images cached locally which is always good to have for many reasons...

- I put some time in writting this so I hope it helps :)